# Linux Serial Port RAW mode

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

Linux Version : 4.9.59

Platform : Raspberry Pi  3 Model B

USB to Serial : FTDI4232

I wish to read a large chunk of data from a machine (about 4096 bytes). All printable data in ASCII format.
The data comes continuously in one transmission; once user has pressed the data transfer button. This operation takes place once in 30 minutes.
The data contains multiple CR LF.

I have configured the serial port as RAW Input Mode.

```
config.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | ECHO | ECHOE);
this->minChars = 5000;
this->timeOut = 100000;
if(this->timeOut > 0)
    config.c_cc[VTIME] = this->timeOut;
else
    config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

if(this->minChars > 0)
    config.c_cc[VMIN] = this->minChars;
else
    config.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
```

---

Reading Function:

```
ready = epoll_wait(this->epfd, &this->events, 1, this->ePollTimeout);
returnVal = read(this->fd, readDataBuffer, 8192);
```

However, when I read from the serial port the system breaks the incoming blob in-to multiple packets and some of the packets are lost.

Eg. : I sent 278 bytes of data.
The system broke this in 3 packets of random length. The length of packet varies each time with execution.
Kindly advice.

Comment: Your code snippets are insufficient to verify that you really have raw mode properly configured.   From the Help page: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."  E.G. your use of epoll_wait() suggests that you're using nonblocking reads, which could behave as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

`read` will read up to the number of bytes you provide, but it doesn't guarantee that many bytes will actually be read. The return value of read is the number of bytes actually read. Typically read syscalls are placed in while loops until the desired number of bytes are actually read, an error occurs, or end of file/stream is reached.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html

Comment: In RAW mode as per documentation either read call returns after timeout value after first character has been received or after minimum number of characters. I am unable to explain sudden return of read system call.

Comment: No it doesn't. There is no timeout on your read call. What is the return value of read?

Comment: @DarkSorrow  *"I am unable to explain sudden return of read system call."* -- So zero-out the timeout value (i.e. VTIME), so that it's a pure counted read, and see what happens.  I wouldn't be surprised if you get the same results (due to likely improper configuration).

Comment: @tweej, I know their is no timeout on read system call but termios structure that configures the UART driver has associated timeout value in RAW mode for read system call. https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios

Comment: @sawdust, Sir I can't use pure counted read as the code need to be generic to handle all bulk block communication. We are developing software to work with similar class of machine (even different manufacturers). The manufacturers do not even guarantees same data byte count between similar models (which may change with firmware version). To make matter worse the end-user can change sample (test) quantity at run-time for different products that will change the byte count of the output. Only timed read is an option.

Comment: @DarkSorrow -- The suggestion of using counted read was not for a final solution, but for testing only to demonstrate that your (hidden) code is faulty.